# gridview header that contains a div

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to put a div inside a header cell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a template field, you could have

```
       <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div> div contents </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```